# How do I scrape pages with URL in the forms of page=0%2C0, page=0%2C1, page=0%2C2... (Using R)

Tags: r

I'm pretty new to using R and have a question about web scraping multiple pages with a different form of page URL.

How should I scrape multiple pages with a for{} loop when the pages are in the form of `page=0%2C0`, `page=0%2C1`, `page=0%2C2`,...?

I tried using the modify_url function to add number after `"0%2C"` however the page remains to be on the first page.

Below is the code I wrote :

```
library(xml2)
library(stringr)
library(httr)

list.url <- 'http://www.epilepsy.com/connect/forums/living-epilepsy-adults?page=0%2C'

post.num <- 1

a<-"0%2C"

for(page.num in 1:10){
  h = read_html(modify_url(list.url, query=list(page=(sprintf('a', page.num)))))
  article_list<- html_nodes(h, 'span.field-content')
  link <- html_nodes(h, 'span.field-content a')
  html_attr(link, 'href')
  article_href <- unique(html_attr(link, 'href'))

  for(link in article_href){
    link = sprintf('http://www.epilepsy.com%s', link)
    print(link)
    h = read_html(link)

    #extracting title
    title = html_text(html_node(h, 'div.panel-pane.pane-node-title.no-title.block'))
    title <- str_trim(title)
    str_replace_all(title, '[[:space:]]', '')
    print(title)

    #extracting contents 
    content = html_text(html_node(h, 'div.field-item.even p'))
    print(content)
    dataf[post.num, 'content'] = content

    #add on post numbers
    post.num <- post.num + 1

  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`modify_url` is more for working with abstract parts of URLS: queries, ports, and so on. You're better off editing the URL as a string (like you describe), so `paste0` fits the bill.

Replace the line

```
h = read_html(modify_url(list.url, query=list(page=(sprintf('a', page.num)))))
```

with

```
h = read_html(paste0(list.url, page.num))
```

I ran the modified code (after commenting out the `dataf` line, since you didn't provide that part), and a lot of different stuff was printed to the console.  So it seems to work.

Comment: Yes it works now! Thank you very much for explaining in detail:)